# How to reset backbone collection in initialize function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to reset collection inside initialize function of Backbone Collection.

Below is my collection

```
var RatesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: RatesModel,
    initialize: function(res){
        var newData = [];
        var rateData = [];
        this.columns = _.keys(res);
        _.each(res, function(val, key){
           // console.log(key);
           // console.log(val);
            newData.push(_.map(val,function(value){
                return [key, value];
            }));
        });
        this.data = _.zip.apply(_,_.values(newData));
        _.each(this.data,function(val){
            rateData.push(_.object(val));
        });
        this.reset( rateData,{silent: true});
        console.log(rateData);
    }
});
```

Here is current jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GswXR/14/.

I tried other way by defining a new function as **getCollection** for the statements inside initialize function and its working as expected.(working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GswXR/12/).

**UPDATE**

I tried to using parse

as shown below

```
 initialize: function(options){
        this.parse(options);
    },
    parse: function(res){
       var newData = [];
        var rateData = [];
        this.columns = _.keys(res);
        _.each(res, function(val, key){
           // console.log(key);
           // console.log(val);
            newData.push(_.map(val,function(value){
                return [key, value];
            }));
        });
        this.data = _.zip.apply(_,_.values(newData));
        _.each(this.data,function(val){
            rateData.push(new RatesModel(_.object(val)));
        });
        console.log(rateData);
        return rateData;
    }
```

but still its not working

Comment: Seems to work as-is.  What's the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/7x8pv/3/

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/GswXR/12/... it should be rendered like this

Comment: Why aren't you using `parse` to rearrange incoming data?

Comment: Your "current" fiddle is assigning an array of simple objects to your collection's `models` property so of course it doesn't work, the `models` in a collection are supposed to be Backbone model instances. Also, your "current" fiddle doesn't match the code in your question.

Comment: ok I will try with parse....

Comment: @muistooshort : Parse worked.... Thanks... Can you add this as answer so that I can accept ?

Comment: You're allowed to answer your own questions and accept those answers (after a short delay). I just pointed out some holes and possible options.